# .find field mongoose not returning anything

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. I'm having problem using the Mongoose find function to return all records matching a field. Could anyone point me to what I'm doing wrong?

```
// GraphQL
query {
  getFieldsByForm(formID:"1234"){
    formID,
    label,
  }
}

// GraphQL Query
export const getFieldsByForm = {
 type: FieldType,
 args: {
   formID: {type: GraphQLString}
 },
 resolve: getFieldsByFormResolver
}

// GraphQL resolver
export async function getFieldsByFormResolver(parentValue, {formID}) {
  return await modelsMongo.Field.find({formID: formID})
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong... sorry.

I had declared this on the GraphQL query:
type: FieldType,

Instead of: 
type: new GraphQLList(FieldType),